# MXF To dash conversion using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I'm trying to convert a mxf to dash using `FFMPEG`. But when i do so the dash file doesnt play in VLC. I have a working dash file (got sample from some website), so i'm sure my VLC seems to work fine and can read dash.

```
ffmpeg -re -i "XXX-05763.mxf" -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 1:v -map 0:v -map 0:a  -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -init_seg_name "init-stream$RepresentationID$-$Bandwidth$.mp4" -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -dash_segment_type mp4 -f dash XXX-05763.mpd
```

Is there something I'm missing in the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out, posting below:

```
ffmpeg -re -i XXX-05763.mxf -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:a aac -c:v libx264 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -frag_type duration -init_seg_name  "init-stream$RepresentationID$-$Bandwidth$.mp4" -b:v 12000k -profile:v main -level:v 3.0  -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" -dash_segment_type mp4 -f dash XXX-05763.mpd
```